# Why is PHP not displaying the correct count of an array?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to count an array using values from a database. Why does PHP only return one? Do I have to iterate all the values?

```
// count the amount of users to display 
public function count_users()
{
    $data = array(); 

    $this->db->select("id","username");
    $this->db->order_by("username","asc"); 
    $query = $this->db->get("users"); 

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $data = $query->row_array();

        echo count($data); // here we echo out the count / num of users. it only displays 1 instead of the correct value, 3
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be using a database wrapper that you haven't mentioned in the question. Please give more details.

Comment: could you do a `print_r($data);`

Comment: what is the type of `$this->db`?

Comment: Looks like you're using some sort of custom library for querying, we can't help you without knowing what it is.

Comment: @sjagr: It looks like CodeIgniter.

Comment: Yes.. It's CI. I forgot to add that in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this also.

As you are using codeigniter, you can check the number of user record with below code.

```
echo $query->num_row();
```

Answer (score 1):

It only returns one row because that's what you asked it for.  `$query->row_array()` returns one *row*.

You want `$query->result_array()`, to get the entire result set.

Comment: I don't think that's quite right. `count()` should return the count of fields in this case.

Comment: @BrianLacy: Ah yes.  I think I mis-understood the issue.

Comment: The OP needs to use a `while` or `foreach` loop to iterate through, no? @RocketHazmat

Comment: @Fred-ii-: To iterate through `$query->result_array()`, yeah.